# The Pit (perhaps)

Tags: identification-request

This novel may have been written prior to the 70s. People could sign up for a motivational course for potential life changing results, however once a waiver was signed the requirements for 'life change'  were revealed to be very unusual, often pitting attendees against each other. In the end, the challenges truly did inspire transformation, likely because of the hardships endured. The most difficult part of the 'course' was having to spend time in an area, 'the pit', thst afforded the deepest challenges but the most transformative results.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What else can you remember about this novel? For example: was it written in English or translated? who were the protagonist(s)? was it set in a modern alternate reality, a dystopic future, or a fantasy world? Any of these details might potentially help someone to find the book for you; we also have a checklist on the [story-ID info page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) which you might like to look through.